(앱시트 오류) APP을 새롭게 만들거나 만들어진 앱에 데이터를 입력하면 에러가 발생됩니다 [An error occurs when creating a new APP or entering data into an already created APP]
Unable to add row to table '소비기한 확인'. → Unable to save image →
{
"error": {
"code": 401,
"message": "The caller does not have permission",
"errors": [
{
"message": "Active session is invalid. Error code: 4",
"domain": "global",
"reason": "authError",
"location": "Authorization",
"locationType": "header"
}
],
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
}
→ Error id 689797be-bdf5-4f86-bed2-1e83514f2003


message: "The caller does not have permission"
Its all in the message, make sure you set the correct authorisations on the caller id.
Search the log's what is missing and add the missing authorisation.
Relational datababes uses a command like "grant" to add then authorisations.

I didn't have a license allocation from the ADMIN console, thank you.
